# How to dynamically create component in a routed module that has not been routed to

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I have an angular application with several routes that load different modules. I want to be able to dynamically create a component from the home page to a module that has not been loaded.

I have the code setup to create the component and it works fine IF the user navigates to that module first.

I tried something like this to preload the module but it doesn't seem to work

```
RouterModule.forRoot(
  appRoutes,
  {
    preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules
  }
)
```

My code looks like this

```
// HTML home page
...
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
...
```

```
// one is home page
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/one', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'one', component: OneComponent},
  { path: 'two', component: TwoComponent}
];
```

I want to be able to create a component in **two** by clicking a button in **one**

Comment: What does it mean to create something on apage that does not exist?

Comment: It means when you first visit a page, there are modules has not been loaded and thus not on the DOM. The modules are only loaded when you visit the link (through routes). If the DOM is not there for the module, you cannot insert any dynamically created DOM element. So you must visit the route first. I want to avoid this problem somehow

Comment: I can't get what you're trying to do. It sounds like a design issue, not implementation.